# Loading freeze for a seconf after call service http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, loading

I'm trying to make a loading when I get data through a service http, and this data is into a scope variable and it show the data into a ng-repeat, like this:

```
<select class="" ng-model="selected_state" ng-change="getArrayCities(selected_state)" material-select watch>
                     <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a state</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="st in usa track by $index" value="{{st}}" >{{st.name}}</option>
</select>

<select class="" ng-model="selected_city" material-select watch ng-disabled="!selected_state">
                     <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a city</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="city in newArrayCities" >{{city.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.loaderRegister = false;
$scope.varloading = false;

    function getArrayCities(a){


                if(a != null){
                    $scope.loaderRegister = true;
                    $scope.varloading = true;

                    var state = JSON.parse(a);
                    ServiceCore.getCities(state.id)
                    .then(
                        function(r){
                            console.log("las ciudades Desde controller",r);
                            $scope.newArrayCities = r;
                            $scope.loaderRegister = false;
                            $scope.varloading = false;

                        },
                        function(e){
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                    );
                }else{

                }

                return true;
            }
```

The problem is , I actvate the loading before a call de service and it finish to recive the data I disable the loading, but the loading freeze for a second ( without move ) and after that it disappear.

I don't know why it happend, I think it wait that ng-repeat finish, but I don't know..

Any help ?

Comment: You said it is freezed for 'a second' so how many items in your list newArrayCities?

Comment: 50 is not enough to make it free for a second. Let try ng-if='varloading == false' before ng-repeat, if it is not work, upload code to plunkr, maybe someone can help.